# Is it possible to pass a Moq object to a C# class constructor?

Tags: c#, class, unit-testing, constructor, moq

I have MyClass class that receives an instance of TheirClass in the constructor. MyClass uses a property value of the instance in MyMethod function, something like this

```
public  class MyClass
{
  ITheirClass theirClass;

 public MyClass( ITheirClass TheirClass)
   {
    theirClass =TheirClass;
   }

  public MyMethod ()
   {
      if (theirClass.TheirProperty) return;
   }
}
```

I would like to create a unit test for MyClass and MyClass.MyMethod function. I created a Moq object like this

```
 var MoqTheirClass = new Mock<ITheirClass>();
 MoqTheirClass.SetupGet(p => p.TheirProperty).Returns(false);
```

But, MoqTheirClass object is not convertible to ITheirClass type and I cannot pass it to the MyClass constructor.

The question is how can I create a Moq TheirClass  object with the preset TheirClass.TheirProperty value and pass it to MyClass constructor?

Is there any other way to unit test MyClass.MyMethod function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the `Object` property from the `MoqTheirClass` object like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(MoqTheirClass.Object);
```